# Extract final url from redirected url

Tags: web-scraping

I'm trying to extract final url from a list of redirected urls, the list is quiet large so I can't do it manually, the "requests" and "urllib.requests" libraries doesn't work for me, it returns me the same initial url. and "selenium" sometime get stuck at some urls, do you have any solutions ?

I tried requests, urllib.requests & selenium